# Pattern type checking in array in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I need to send requests to a REST API in which the headers can only have a string as an index and a string or a number as the value `[string, string | number]` which would look like this in the form of an array for one header. Now I have the problem that I of course don't just want to send one custom header at a time and a array could look like this `[['value1', 10], ['value2', 'value']`. How would I go about type checking a repetitive pattern like this?

I already tried to just define it in the function which makes the call to the API like following `functionname(header : [[string, string | number]])` which would only let me add one custom header and then give me a type error. I also tried some other stuff by defining it as it's own type like the following `type headerFormat = [[string, string | number], headerFormat[]]` but that also didn't work.

Comment: I may have misunderstood the requirements, but does `[string, string | number][]` work? That will allow you to have an array of 0 or more elements, and each element must be a `[string, string | number]` tuple

Comment: Oh that actually worked and I hadn't tried that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could also just define a `Record<string, string | number>` and then call `Object.entries` on it and it will give you an array with that same structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an array of 0 or more elements, where each element is a `[string, string | number]` tuple, that can be done like this:

```
type HeaderFormat = [string, string | number][]
```

If you want to require that the outer array has to have at least one element, you can do that like:

```
type HeaderFormat = [[string, string | number], ...[string, string | number][]]
```

Same thing but perhaps a bit easier to read:

```
type SingleHeader = [string, string | number]
type HeaderFormat = [SingleHeader, ...SingleHeader[]]
```